# serverless and connection via pymongo and connection pooling

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pymongo, serverless

I am developing a function in aws lambda/serverless and was wondering how to get connection pooling done. From a programmatic point of view I know how to establish a pymongo connection with pooling, but no idea how to achieve this with serverless since it is stateless and every invocation would then trigger a new connection (and in theory a lot at the same time).

Any advice?

Comment: I have a mongo / aws lambda / serverless function running in my small production app. I would say that pooling is not really an option and the connection should be established on invoking the function and closed at the end. Curious to see if people have better ideas/experiences.